# Regex - Issues with using Boundary to excluding words

Tags: regex, word-boundary

In my authentification web site, I'm using regex to control a blacklist password. (example of blacklisted password : 12345678, 123456789, baseball, football)

I would like to add new regex rule (using boundary), which will exclude words (black listed password). I have read some similar questions on StackOverflow and tried to declare it with something like this:

```
^(?!\b12345678\b|\b123456789\b|\bbaseball\b|\bfootball\b|\bsuperman\b).*$
```

this regex doesn't match the words above, it's correct. For exemple "Baseball" with a letter, number or special character (before or after the "baseball") must match.

But "**baseball!**" doesn't match contrary to "**!baseball**". Can you give me some advices how to do it?

Comment: I don't get your question. You lost me at *"it's correct"*... If it's a blacklist and those are ***passwords***, than if `baseball` is blacklisted, than `baseballz`, `thebaseball` or `#baseball` passwords should do what exactly? Pass of fail?

Comment: Also, if those are ***passwords*** (clearly a password is not a sentence) than why you use the word boundary `\b` at all? why not imply `^(evil|monster)$` ?

Comment: baseballz, thebaseball, #baseball  must pass. If I use something like ^(evil|monster)$, evil123, evil#abc will not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But "**baseball!**" doesn't match contrary to "**!baseball**"…

`baseball!` doesn't match because your pattern doesn't allow `baseball` at the beginning (`^` followed by a negative lookahead for `baseball`).
`!baseball` in contrast matches because `!` is placed at the beginning, and the negative lookahead is done only there, not aft.
One could think of putting the `.*` at different places, but that will lead to nothing.
Just include the anchors `^` `$` in the lookahead:

```
(?!^(12345678|123456789|baseball|football|superman)$)^.*$
```

(in fact, we could even drop the initial `^`).